# Code for 3d image cube is not working

Tags: css, transform, perspective

Specifically the perspective and transform properties are not working in css code provided below. Also, the radio buttons work but they do not link to the correct side of the cube. I can't spot the problem.

```
 $size: 500px; // cube length
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
 } 
 .scene {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
 }
.cube3d {
display: inline-block;
  position: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.cube-face {

  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
// faces
.cube-face-front {
  background: yellow;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
}  
.cube-face-back {
  background: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
} 
.cube-face-left {
  background: green;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
} 
.cube-face-right {
  background: magenta;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
} 
.cube-face-top {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
} 
.cube-face-bottom {
  background: red;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, $size/2);
}  
// controls 

#radio-back:checked ~ .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
} 
#radio-left:checked ~ .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(90deg); 
} 
#radio-right:checked ~ .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg); 
}
#radio-top:checked ~ .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg); 
}  
#radio-bottom:checked ~ .scene .cube {
  transform: rotateX(90deg); 
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well. A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be very helpful too.

Comment: What's `$size: 500px;`?